# Finding dll dependencies

Tags: c#, dll

I'm building a program in C# and I use a lot of dlls. However, I believe I am only using a small amount of functions from each dll, and so wondered if it were possible to somehow access the dlls and extract only the used functions into a separate dll.

Or in other words, say I have 2 dlls A and B. A has functions a,b and c, and B has functions 1, 2 and 3. If I only use a and 2, is there any way (or is it even legal??) to somehow make a third dll C with only a and 2 in?

The aim is so I don't have to reference 2 (actually more like 20) and instead only need 1.

Is this possible / legal???? I know Microsoft have a tool which allows the combination of dlls into one, but I don't know how to edit them or anything... can anyone explain?

Comment: I do not know if it is legal or not (you should carefully read the EULA if these assemblies were made by Microsoft, or the user License if they were provided by a third party).
Anyway, what you could do to limit the number of references, is to create a single Library having all the necessary references, named "External/Helper Methods" for instance, and use it as your only repository. This way you would have a single reference instead of 20.

NotaBene : this solution may not be applicable, if for instance the methods you use have as parameter other classes defined in the same assembly.

Comment: As far as know there is not such thing. If the dlls are yours - and I believe they don't - you could merge the sources. But you can't change code that someone else owns and "bake your own cake" with those codes... and I hope this never become possible, otherwise will be a mess...

Answer (score 0):

@Mattb2291: I would suggest a different approach. take a class C which is having function a and 2. Class A and Class B should inherit from C. In class C provide a base implementation to method a and 2.

But for that certain things you need to keep in mind:

first, are class A and B related to same problem domain from aspect of OOPs? 
second, if method a and 2 are accessing any class member within their respective classes, you have to move them to Class C. You code might look like:

```
class C{
    void a(){
    }

    void 2(){
    }
}

class A:C{
}

class B:C{
}
```

This answer is from the perspective of OPPs. you must verify it before implementing in your project.